# Android Webview Page Loaded Event

Tags: android, cordova, webview, hybrid

I'm writing an SDK for android which needs to injects JavaScript code into webviews it finds by enumerating the UI.

After finding a webview, the code sets a *WebViewClient* by using *setWebViewClient()* and waits for *onPageFinished()* to perform the actual injection.

All was working well, until I tried to use this method on a **Cordova 8** application.

The WebView used by **Cordova 8** is a subclass (*org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebView*) that overrides the *setWebViewClient()* method in the following way:

```
public void setWebViewClient(WebViewClient client) {
    this.viewClient = (SystemWebViewClient)client;
    super.setWebViewClient(client);
 }
```

Because of the casting to *SystemWebViewClient*, I get a cast  exception.

I want my solution to be as generic as possible, so extending *SystemWebViewClient* is not an option, but I still need to know when the webview page is loaded in order to inject the JavaScript.

Is there any way to get a notification when a webview has finished loading a page without using *WebViewClient* and *webView.setWebViewClient()* ?

Answer (score 0):

A potential workaround would be to use WebChromeClient instead, and override its onProgressChanged method as follows:

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        if (newProgress == 100) {
            // Do your injection here
        }
    }
});
```